# event.preventDefault() doesn't work and form still submits

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to use event.preventDefault(); but my form still submitts.
and gives me a page with json response. There isn't any error in my console.

Here is my scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add_to_cart ').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(event.target);
    var data = $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({

      url: $form.attr('action'),
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      data: data,
      success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        var message = response.message;

        showToastMessage(message, 'toast-success');
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus) {
      var message = "Error.";
      if (xhr.responseText) {
        var error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (error) {
          error = error.message;
          if (error) {
            message = error;
          }
        }
      }
      showToastMessage(message, 'toast-error')
    });
    return false;
  });

});

function showToastMessage(message, type) {
  var $toastElem = $("#snackbar");
  $toastElem.className = "show";
  $toastElem.html(message).removeClass('toast-success').removeClass('toast-error').addClass(type).addClass('show');

}
```

I have seen most of the question about this problom, but I still have problom.

html:

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.add', $product->id) }}" method="POST" id="add_to_cart">
  <a href="javascript:{}" rel="nofollow" data-nid="4165" class="cart-button ripple add-to-cart has-ripple" onclick="parent().submit();";>add</a>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please share screenshot of browser console panel

Comment: It doesn't show any thing.

Comment: Did you make sure you're using jQuery? Your code works fine as long as you have properly implemented jQuery before executing your code.

Comment: yes, I'm sure,  every thing is ok. my toast message is working. but, it just still submit the form.

Comment: [event.preventDefault() works fine](https://jsbin.com/teqepereqo/1/edit?html,js,output), there must be some other problem that is preventing the function from running in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. yes, you are right. I had a basic syntax mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

> ```
> <a href="javascript:{}" rel="nofollow" data-nid="4165" class="cart-button ripple add-to-cart has-ripple" onclick="parent().submit();";>add</a>
> ```

Submit events are only triggered by the form submission is triggered by standard submission methods (like submit buttons).

Calling the `submit()` method of the form using JavaScript will bypass the submit event entirely.

Since the event doesn't fire, the event listener function isn't called, so `event.preventDefault()` is never called.

Use a submit button instead of a link that doesn't go to a useful URL with some JS attached to it.

Comment: Thanks, but I had a simple syntax mistake. now every thing is ok.